# Laravel: wont' send the Email

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

When using the Mail function in Laravel I am getting the error shown below.

I have tried both first having all the data in the .env file and picking it up from the config/mail.php

then hardcoding it in the mail.php in case it was not getting it from there.

I have also tried different ports, 465 the one expected, but also 587 and 25 but to no change.

I have also tried different smtp servers, and I have tried different (which work) Mails in other websites. So it is not my server down or smth like that.

I use this to register users and then send them a confirmation mail to click on. They get saved in the table alright, but at the time of sending the mail, it won't go out.

I have also tried to hardcode the To: address in the controller file, in case it was not getting it from the $data array. No change.

```
Mail::send('auth.emails.register', ['data' => $data ], function($mail) use($data) {        $mail->from('a@chefpi.com', 'Your Application');
                $mail->subject('Confirm your mail');
                $mail->to($data['email'], $data['name']);
                });                
            return redirect("auth/register")
            ->with("message", "A confirmation link has been sent to your email");           
        }
```

You can see in the Error display that it does get the To address and the Confirm_token (which were also saved in the Table)

the Error read goes like this:

```
 Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 404:
    Connection to server.websitehostserver.net:465 Timed Out
    in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 404
    at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse('0') in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 289
    at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_readGreeting() in 

        AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 117
        at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() in Mailer.php line 79
        at Swift_Mailer->send(object(Swift_Message), array()) in Mailer.php line 386
        at Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(object(Swift_Message)) in Mailer.php line 173
        at Mailer->send('auth.emails.register', array('data' => array('name' => 'aaaaa', 'email' => 'madina@yandex.ru', 'confirm_token' => 'x5nSRdqgPApFWUvwlNcMLmwvMQ1T64IKpfX0IHjqm7zjwfDYEhCSGPixJyNky2XU5')), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 6222
        at Facade::__callStatic('send', array('auth.emails.register', array('data' => array('name' => 'aaaaa', 'email' => 'madina@yandex.ru', 'confirm_token' => 'x5nSRdqgPApFWUvwKtwdzwT64IKpfX0IHjqm7zjwfDYEhCSGPixJyNky2XU5')), object(Closure))) in AuthController.php line 84
        at Mail::send('auth.emails.register', array('data' => array('name' => 'aaaaa', 'email' => 'mayarodina@yandex.ru', 'confirm_token' => 'x5nSRdqgPApFbHWqszKtwdzwT64IKpfX0IHjqm7zjwfDYEhCSGPixJyNky2XU5')), object(Closure)) 

    in AuthController.php line 84
```

I am adding the Full Controller, just in case:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function postRegister(Request $request){

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:16|regex:/^[a-záéíóúàèìòùäëïöüñ\s]+$/i',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:18|confirmed',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'This field is required',

        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            return redirect("auth/register")
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
        }
        else{
            $user = new User;
            $data['name'] = $user->name = $request->name;
            $data['email'] = $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->remember_token = str_random(100);
            $data['confirm_token'] = $user->confirm_token = str_random(100);
            $user->save();

            Mail::send('auth.emails.register', ['data' => $data ], function($mail) use($data) {

                $mail->from('a@chefpisos.com', 'Your Application');
                $mail->subject('Confirm your mail');
                $mail->to($data['email'], $data['name']);

            });

            return redirect("auth/register")
            ->with("message", "A confirmation link has been sent to your email");



        }


    }

    public function confirmRegister($email, $confirm_token)
    {


    $user = new User;

    $the_user = $user->select()->where('email', '=', $email)
                               ->where('confirm_token', '=', $confirm_token)
                               ->get();

    if (count($the_user) > 0)
    {
       $active = 1;
       $confirm_token = str_random(100);
       $user ->where('email', '=', $email)
       ->update(['active' => $active, 'confirm_token' => $confirm_token]);
       return redirect('auth/register')
       ->with("message", 'Congrats'. $the_user[0]['name'] . 'account activated');
    }

    else{

        return redirect('/');
    }

    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request){







       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'active' => 1])) {

             return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());   

            }

            else{
                $rules = [
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    'password' => 'required',
                ];

                $messages = [
                    'email.required' => 'El campo email es requerido',
                    'email.email' => 'El formato de email es incorrecto',
                    'password.required' => 'El campo password es requerido',
                ];

                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

                return redirect('auth/login')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput()
                ->with('message', 'Error al iniciar sesión');
    }


    }









}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going against what my web hosting provider states that I have to use 465, I went for 587 and I don't know why, but this time it worked.

The strange thing is that I have another website hosted in the same server and I use there the 465 without any issue.

However, it would not go out through that port in my other web. I will never know why.

I have read all the similar cases on the internet and all of them did have issues with port 465 and finally worked using the other one.

If you come across a similar issue, just copy my code above, it is complete and works.

Thanks to all those who had a look at the issue.